# Prevent cross domain websocket request

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a websocket server for my web application at url: http://example.com:8080 when I ran it on the server it works well for my domain http://anotherdomain.com but it servers well for other domains too http://baddomain.com
What i want is to prevent other domains from accessing my websocket, ie I want that only my domain can have access to my websocket what can I do?

I am using **ws** module of nodejs (https://github.com/websockets/ws)

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port:8080})

wss.on('connection', ws => {
    ws.on('message', data => {
        // something here
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this, is to check the IP.
You can get it from the request object passed to the on.connection event.

```
wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
    ws.on('message', data => {
        let _thisIP = req.connection.localAddress; //you can compare it now
    })
})
```

Comment: i got the address! great, tysm